# Is it possible to execute raw SQL with Ormlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I am using Ormlite in my Android project and I would like to know if it is possible to execute raw sql, for insertion for instance. I am not wanting to use `QueryBuilder` because I simply want to import a SQLite dump in my db the first time the app is launched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can! From the Dao class you can just call executeRaw passing the query as a String. Something like:

```
this.getDao().executeRaw("UPDATE " + this.getTableName() + " SET number = " + String.valueOf(count) + " WHERE id = " + myId);
```

Comment: Thanx a lot @Javi Armendáriz!